# Responsive design gets scaled out on Blackberry

Tags: html, responsive-design, meta

I'm having a problem with my responsive design being scaled out on a Blackberry (Curve 8520). Works great everywhere else.

It has the site completely zoomed out very small and requires lots of zooming in which it needs to be displayed at 100%.

Everything is set up in percentages, and is using media queries to target a screen size, this is working fine as the phone is using the style set for this device, just that its fully zoomed out.

I understand it may be down to the construction of my viewport meta tag and have tried lots of alternatives based on research on the net, these are enclosed below what I have tried and none have worked:

Current:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Please note, each one that has been separated by a space is a new set of code I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use the viewport tag settings found on this page and it should work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag